# StreamSupport collector and java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, java-stream

I'm trying to use [StreamSupport](https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport) in order to explore stream on Java 7. I've added `streamsupport-1.5.4.jar` to my project and written a code like this:

```
import java8.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FinantialStatement {

    private List<Rubric> values;

    public List<Rubric> getConsolidatedRubrics() {
        List<Rubric> rubrics = values.stream().sorted((Rubric r1, Rubric r2) -> r1.getOrder().compareTo(r2.getOrder())).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        return rubrics;
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector<Object,capture#1-of
?,Collection<Object>> to Collector<? super Rubric,A,R>
```

I've tried to apply the hint proposed by Eclipse

```
Add cast to '(Collector<? super Rubric, A, R>)'
```

but it has not solved the problem.

Does someone have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [streamsupport](https://github.com/stefan-zobel/streamsupport) entry points to receive a `java8.util.stream.Stream` from a `java.util.Collection` are mainly

1) [java8.util.stream.StreamSupport#stream](http://static.javadoc.io/net.sourceforge.streamsupport/streamsupport/1.5.4/java8/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Collection-)

2) [java8.util.stream.StreamSupport#parallelStream](http://static.javadoc.io/net.sourceforge.streamsupport/streamsupport/1.5.4/java8/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#parallelStream-java.util.Collection-)

So, your code snippet should look like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import java8.util.stream.Collectors;
import java8.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class FinantialStatement {

    private List<Rubric> values;

    public List<Rubric> getConsolidatedRubrics() {
        List<Rubric> rubrics = StreamSupport.stream(values)
                .sorted((Rubric r1, Rubric r2) -> r1.getOrder().compareTo(r2.getOrder()))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        return rubrics;
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

Obviously you can't use `java.util.Collection#stream()` because that

> a) is a method that only exists in Java 8 and
>
> b) it mingles
>   `java.util.stream.Collectors` with your (correct)
>   java**8**.util.stream.Collectors import

(Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of streamsupport)